# google actions sdk: how to include an audio when displaying a basic card response

Tags: actions-on-google

when responding to a user query using actions sdk I am able to create a basic card using:

```
conv.ask(new BasicCard({
  text: 'Text with card display',
  title: 'Title:',
  display: 'CROPPED',
}));
```

However, if I wish to provide the user with some audio (different from the display text) how do I do it?

I tried to add a `conv.ask('<speak>' + 'Hello' + '</speak>');` but it throws a error

```
MalformedResponse
expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt.items[0].simple_response: 'display_text' must be set or 'ssml' must have a valid display rendering.
```

What is the best way to include an audio in a google actions project? Thanks

Comment: "Hello" doesn't sound like some audio. Are you trying to send an audio file? Can you show exactly how you actually have formatted the request?

Comment: @Prisoner: Let me rephrase the question. In a Basic Card I want a spoken audio that is different from the text that will be shown to the user. If so, how do I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Basic Card does not have audio attached to it. As the name suggests, it is a visual cue rather than an audible one. It is meant to supplement the text that is spoken and displayed - not replace it.

While you can create a SimpleResponse that has different text that is spoken vs displayed, you should make sure that both responses are substantially the same. You can use a [SimpleResponse](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_response.simpleresponse.html) with something like this:

```
conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
  speech: '<speak>Here are the results, showing our sunny recreational facilities. <audio src="https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/animals/cicada_chirp.ogg">And the sounds of nature.</audio></speak>',
  text: 'Here is the result',
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play the audio in the background, I'd suggest using [SSML](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml), but if your actual goal is to just deliver the audio to the user (like if it's a podcast or something) you can use a [Media Response](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses).

If, however, you want the text displayed on a device with a screen to be **different** from the text that's spoken, you could add a [Simple Response](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#simple_responses) (which has the option to add different text and speech).

Comment: Thanks @lukedavis for your response. I am using Simple Response for other needs. But as mentioned in my query I wanted an audio that accompanies a Basic Card and wanted to know if there is an elegant way to do it. The work around I am doing is having a simple Response before it that contains the audio that I want with a text that is of just a few words (like a Title).